# Is there a problem with Pinata Discord Server?

Tags: ipfs, meta-data, pinata

I want to access their server but I am not able to do it. The link they have on their website keeps failing: https://discord.com/invite/pinata.

Does anybody have a valid invite I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be a problem with that link but it was fixed by the team. It should work now.